# CSS sliding doors with 3 pictures, hover effect issue

Tags: css

I'm having problem with the hover effect.

```
<li class"menuButton facorits>
 <div class="menuButtonLeft></div>
 <div class="menuButtonMiddle>
   <div class="favotisIcon"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="menuButtonRight"></div>
</li>


 .menuButton:hover > div {
     background-position: right -40px;
     cursor: pointer;
  }

  .menuButtonLeft{
      background: url("left.png") no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
      float: left;
      width: 5px;
      height: 100%;
   }

  .menuButtonMiddle{
      background: url("Middle.png") no-repeat scroll -5px 0px transparent;
      float: left;
   }

  .menuButtonRight{
      background: url("right.png") no-repeat scroll -224px 0 transparent;
      float: left;
      width: 5px;
      height: 100%;
   }
```

I'm using sliding door css with 3 images. problem is that when I set the background-position it looks like each picture starts from the same x y position... All pictures are in a sprite (original, hover , active under each other)

Is it possible to only set the Y value off all those 3 pictures in one "selector"?

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/k4RjV/16/ somthing like this. If you hover on the button you can see that the x y cordinates are wrong for the left and right picture.

Comment: It might be helpful to see the css you have assigned to .menuButtonLeft, .menuButtonMiddle and .menuButtonRight

Comment: You'll need to show us the images and the style for the hover, too. Best would be an online example, either on your site or with jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k4RjV/16/ somthing like this. If you hover on the button you can see that the x y cordinates are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do.

You can't set different values for objects with the same selector, the most recent one will just replace the previous ones.

EDIT: Is this what you wanted to do?

```
li div {
    background-position-y: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after. It works in IE8 but not in FF, why?

Comment: `background-position-y` is a very new property that isn't supported widely yet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the new background position for each `div` separately, since each has a different horizontal position and it's not possible to set the vertical position alone:

```
.menuButton:hover .menuButtonLeft {
    background-position: 0px -29px;
}

.menuButton:hover .menuButtonMiddle {
    background-position: -5px -29px;
}

.menuButton:hover .menuButtonRight {
    background-position: -130.8px -29px;
}
```

NB: Any special reason for the non-integer `px` value? It's not technically wrong, but usually makes no sense.

Comment: sorry about that non-integer px, but I used firebug and copy the code so .. :)

Comment: If you use hover on every div, only that part (image) will get hover effect and not the entire button.

Comment: @Plexus: Look at my code. The `:hover` is still defined on the whole `.menuButton`.